# Entity Framework Core: InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to setup a method that returns all presentations that are not overlapping with presentations you have signed up for. However, when trying to implement this I came across an error I can't seem to fix, I looked around and haven't been able to find any similar issues. Am I missing something obvious?

This is the Error:

> InvalidOperationException: variable 't0' of type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[NameSpace.Models.Presentation,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]'
>   referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

These are my models.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Presentation> MyPresentations { get; set; }

    public List<PresentationUser> RegisteredPresentations { get; set; }
}

public class Presentation
{
    public int PresentationId { get; set; }

    public string HostId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Host { get; set; }

    public List<PresentationUser> Attendees { get; set; }

    public int TimeId { get; set; }
    public PresentationTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class PresentationUser
{
    public int PresentationId { get; set; }
    public Presentation Presentation { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class PresentationTime
{
    public int PresentationTimeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method I can't get to work

```
private async Task<IQueryable<Presentation>> GetAvailablePresentations()
{
    User user = await context.Users
        .Include(u => u.RegisteredPresentations)
        .ThenInclude(eu => eu.Presentation.Host)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userManager.GetUserId(User));


    var Presentations = context.Presentations
        .Include(e => e.Host)
        .Include(e => e.Time)
        .Include(e => e.Attendees)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.ApplicationUser)
        // Filter Out Conditions
        .Where(e => e.Attendees.All(u => u.ApplicationUserId != user.Id))    // Cannot see Presentations they are attending.
        .Where(e => e.HostId != user.Id);                                    // Cannot see their own Presentation  

    var debug = user.RegisteredPresentations.Select(ex => ex.Presentation).ToList();

    // This section makes it so that users can't sign up for more that one Presentation per timeslot.
    // Error Occurs Here
    Presentations = Presentations.Where(e => debug.All(ex =>
        ex.Time.EndTime < e.Time.StartTime || e.Time.EndTime < ex.Time.StartTime));
    // This also does not work
    // Presentations = Presentations.Where(e => debug.All(ex => ex.Time.StartTime != e.Time.StartTime));


    return Presentations;
}
```

If anyone can help me fix this it would be huge help.

Note: I stripped a lot of other logic to help isolate this issue, so I may have a couple unnecessary `.Include()` in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Presentations` is not a list, it's still a `IQueryable` - a not-yet-executed query to DB. Applying `Where` you instruct EF to apply additional `WHERE` in SQL.
But `debug` is a list of objects in memory (`.ToList()`). How you think EF will transfer them back to DB?

If you want all filtering be applied in DB - you should change `debug` to list of something "simple" (list of ids?) - then EF will be able to pass this list back to DB.

Alternatively, you should read all suitable Presentations into memory (call `.ToList()`) and apply last filtering in memory. You may calculate min(StartTime) and max(EndTime) from `debug` and apply this two simple values to Presentations query (you will receive less unnecessary items) then read to memory and apply "strong" filtering in memory.